# Is this a depiction of Lightsaber Form VII Juyo?

Tags: star-wars

Yeah I know that Darth Maul is a Juyo practicioner, but is this a Juyo stance?[image: Darth Maul Death Sentence #4 cover]

Comment: Seems interesting cover.. inspired from `Star Wars: The Clone Wars` season 4-5, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how the stances used to describe Jedi combat have not been officially codified, only described in passing detail, it would be impossible to determine if this particular image was able to show a [Juyo stance](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII:_Juyo_/_Vaapad).

- Juyo is described as a particularly violent and offensive style but the artist may have simply been told to present a sinister-appearing Darth Maul. Judging from the image, it would appear that the lightsaber he is using was once a double bladed one and now only has one blade.
- This may be why he is choosing a different hold on the blade, inconsistent with the double-bladed technique he has normally been shown using. Juyo likely comes with a one-bladed technique, since one could not always depend on having a double-bladed lightsaber handy, or as the image shows, your lightsaber may fall apart during a struggle as well.
- As to its veracity as a technique of the Juyo fighting style, only a Jedi master would be able to tell us for certain.

[image: Darth Maul vs Qui-Gon Jinn and Obi-wan Kenobi]

Comment: Why is Qui-gon's lightsaber so much thin in this picture?